# How to connect multiple projects to one Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with Angular and Firestore.

I have one admin web and client app.
I tried to paste into client app the firebase databaseURL of admin web.
However, this error occurred `ERROR Error: The Cloud Firestore API is not enabled for the project [project name]`.

I know how to connect projects to one **realtime database**.
So instead, I'd like to know how to connect projects to one **Firestore**.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already enable Firestore in your project? If you did and still get this error, go to this link adding your project ID at the end and enable the Firestore API

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firestore.googleapis.com/?q=firestore&id=f9a0621f-e2f6-4fa0-9cb6-8af074022c04&project=

If you haven't enabled Firestore, Go to your Firebase console under Develop > Database > Cloud Firestore and enable it.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do it